# How to add partially-shaded error bars to dygraph plot

Tags: r, plot, dygraphs, errorbar

I am new to R software. My CSV data contain more than 10,000 units (rows) and two variables (columns). Data were recorded every twenty minutes (72 times per day) for six months using data logger. Here sample data and dygraph plotted using R.

dput(Preharvest)

```
tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"))

Names = c("Datetime", 
"Temp", "RH", "X"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5552L
))
```

> ```
> Datetime          Temp    RH
> 2014-08-30 8:00   21.6    70.3
> 2014-08-30 8:20   21.7    69.8
> 2014-08-30 8:40   22.1    70.3
> 2014-08-30 9:00   22.5    70.8
> 2014-08-30 9:20   22.7    70.9
> 2014-08-30 9:40   23.3    71.5
> 2014-08-30 10:00  23.4    70.4
> 2014-08-30 10:20  23.8    71.3
> 2014-08-30 10:40  24.4    71.6
> 2014-08-30 11:00  25      71.7
> 2014-08-30 11:20  25.7    68.2
> 2014-08-30 11:40  25.8    63.8
> 2014-08-30 12:00  26.4    63.9
> 2014-08-30 12:20  27.5    65.1
> 2014-08-30 12:40  28.1    62.6
> 2014-08-30 13:00  28.4    61.1
> 2014-08-30 13:20  28.4    60.1
> 2014-08-30 13:40  28.2    59.3
> 2014-08-30 14:00  28      58.3
> 2014-08-30 14:20  27.6    56.9
> 2014-08-30 14:40  27.4    57.1
> 2014-08-30 15:00  27.3    57.3
> 2014-08-30 15:20  27.4    57.5
> 2014-08-30 15:40  27.4    57.4
> 2014-08-30 16:00  27.5    57.2
> 2014-08-30 16:20  27.6    57.2
> 2014-08-30 16:40  27.6    57
> 2014-08-30 17:00  27.5    55.8
> 2014-08-30 17:20  27.4    55.8
> 2014-08-30 17:40  27.3    55.4
> 2014-08-30 18:00  27.2    55.8
> 2014-08-30 18:20  27.1    55.8
> 2014-08-30 18:40  27      55.8
> 2014-08-30 19:00  26.8    55.4
> 2014-08-30 19:20  26.6    55.6
> 2014-08-30 19:40  26.5    55.3
> 2014-08-30 20:00  26.1    54.7
> 2014-08-30 20:20  25.8    54.5
> 2014-08-30 20:40  25.5    55.3
> 2014-08-30 21:00  25.4    55.6
> 2014-08-30 21:20  25.4    55.9
> 2014-08-30 21:40  25.4    56.1
> 2014-08-30 22:00  25.4    56.1
> 2014-08-30 22:20  24.8    55.9
> 2014-08-30 22:40  24.3    56.6
> 2014-08-30 23:00  23.8    57.4
> 2014-08-30 23:20  23.5    58
> 2014-08-30 23:40  23.1    58.6
> 2014-08-31 0:00   22.9    59.2
> 2014-08-31 0:20   22.6    59.8
> 2014-08-31 0:40   22.4    60.3
> 2014-08-31 1:00   22.3    60.8
> 2014-08-31 1:20   22.1    61.3
> 2014-08-31 1:40   22  61.7
> 2014-08-31 2:00   21.8    62.2
> 2014-08-31 2:20   21.7    62.6
> 2014-08-31 2:40   21.6    63
> 2014-08-31 3:00   21.6    63.4
> 2014-08-31 3:20   21.5    63.7
> 2014-08-31 3:40   21.4    64
> 2014-08-31 4:00   21.4    64.4
> 2014-08-31 4:20   21.3    64.7
> 2014-08-31 4:40   21.2    65
> 2014-08-31 5:00   21.2    65.2
> 2014-08-31 5:20   21.1    65.5
> 2014-08-31 5:40   21.1    65.8
> 2014-08-31 6:00   21.1    65.9
> 2014-08-31 6:20   21      66.2
> 2014-08-31 6:40   21      66.4
> 2014-08-31 7:00   21.1    67.3
> 2014-08-31 7:20   21.2    68.1
> 2014-08-31 7:40   21.6    67.6
> 2014-08-31 8:00   21.7    67.9
> 2014-08-31 8:20   22.1    68.9
> 2014-08-31 8:40   22.1    67.7
> 2014-08-31 9:00   22.1    68
> 2014-08-31 9:20   22.7    70.4
> 2014-08-31 9:40   24.9    70.6
> 2014-08-31 10:00  26.2    62.3
> 2014-08-31 10:20  26.8    62.4
> 2014-08-31 10:40  27.6    62.4
> 2014-08-31 11:00  27.8    60.3
> 2014-08-31 11:20  27.7    58.1
> 2014-08-31 11:40  27.2    56.4
> 2014-08-31 12:00  28.8    51.6
> 2014-08-31 12:20  27.5    54.8
> 2014-08-31 12:40  27.2    55.6
> 2014-08-31 13:00  27.9    58.5
> 2014-08-31 13:20  27.3    58.6
> 2014-08-31 13:40  27.2    58.4
> 2014-08-31 14:00  27      59
> 2014-08-31 14:20  26.7    59.3
> 2014-08-31 14:40  26.8    59.4
> 2014-08-31 15:00  26.2    58.2
> 2014-08-31 15:20  25.6    58.3
> 2014-08-31 15:40  26      59.6
> 2014-08-31 16:00  26.8    61.5
> 2014-08-31 16:20  27.6    61.8
> 2014-08-31 16:40  27.8    61.2
> 2014-08-31 17:00  27.7    59.2
> 2014-08-31 17:20  28.1    59.3
> 2014-08-31 17:40  28.5    58.4
> 2014-08-31 18:00  28.5    57.7
> 2014-08-31 18:20  28.9    57.3
> 2014-08-31 18:40  29.3    53.3
> 2014-08-31 19:00  28.6    51.5
> 2014-08-31 19:20  27.8    51.2
> 2014-08-31 19:40  27.1    51.5
> 2014-08-31 20:00  26.6    51.9
> 2014-08-31 20:20  26.3    53.2
> 2014-08-31 20:40  25.7    55.2
> 2014-08-31 21:00  25.2    68.1
> 2014-08-31 21:20  26      58.1
> 2014-08-31 21:40  25      58.3
> 2014-08-31 22:00  24.5    59.1
> 2014-08-31 22:20  23.8    59.2
> 2014-08-31 22:40  23.3    59.7
> 2014-08-31 23:00  22.9    60.3
> 2014-08-31 23:20  22.6    61.1
> 2014-08-31 23:40  22.5    61.5
> 2014-09-01 0:00   22.4    61.9
> 2014-09-01 0:20   22.3    62.2
> 2014-09-01 0:40   22.3    62.6
> 2014-09-01 1:00   22.2    62.9
> 2014-09-01 1:20   22.2    63.1
> 2014-09-01 1:40   22.1    63.4
> 2014-09-01 2:00   22.2    63.8
> 2014-09-01 2:20   22.2    64.1
> 2014-09-01 2:40   22.2    64.4
> 2014-09-01 3:00   22.1    64.7
> 2014-09-01 3:20   22.1    65
> 2014-09-01 3:40   22.1    65.4
> ```

```
Preharvest<- read.csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Preharvest.csv")
Preharvest1<- as.data.frame(Preharvest  , header=True)
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)
s <-xts(Preharvest1[, 2:3], order.by=as.POSIXct(Preharvest1$Datetime))  
dygraph(s)
```

[Sample dygraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6HWd.jpg)

However, I would like to have dygraph with error bars of partial shade with time series. Here sample dygraph was taken from internet that I would like to have.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq1sD.jpg)

Is there anyone help me and guide to have dygraph with error bars based on a daily mean of the data with partial shade?

Comment: Could you explain more on what you are trying to do? The two images you've posted look pretty much the same. Anyway it would be good if you give more context, explain more on what have you done and did not work, and any way to try and narrow down your question. It's a bit difficult to try to answer your question as it is formulated right now. Thanks.

Comment: can you use dput() to add your dataset (just a subset) to your post?

Comment: @lrnzcig, the first graph was plotted based on data collected in 20 minutes interval for six months, while the second dygraph with shade is sample taken from internet and a type I would like to have at end. So, how can I convert data taken every 20 minutes interval to daily base mean (24 hours), then plot a dygraph and show the daily variation with partial shade?

Comment: @MLavoie, I didn't understand what do you mean. Do you mean add data to my post using dput()? I so, how?

Comment: in r, just type: dput(yourdataset) and copy the content in your post

Comment: @MLavoie, I did just above sample data.

Comment: in your R console, it should start with something like that: structure(list(Sepal.Length  = c(

Comment: Also, read the dygraphs documentation and figure out what function adds error-bars to plots. And when you say 'partially-shaded', that's probably called transparency or alpha-blending.

Comment: @MLavoie, is that something like this?

Comment: @MLavoie, Is that something like this?                                                 tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"))                                                                                                  also posted above the sample data.

Comment: there is still something missing from the dput() content but this https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-upper-lower-bars.html is what you need I believe

Comment: @MLavoie, yes exactly.

Comment: @ lrnzcig, yes you are correct. Both graphs are the same. Sorry for that! Here is the link (http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/range-selector) and I would like to plot the second type of graph.